# Changing PopupMenu color in AppCompat

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

I am migrating my app to `AppCompat Light` styles from `Holo`. One thing I can't get right is to **style the spinner's popupmenu background**, something I had working for Holo, but the same tricks just don't work. I've also used the recommended styles found here in SO on similar questions (most of which I had already tried) without any success.

Please take a look at my root style and PopupMenu style to see if you see anything wrong.

```
<!-- ROOT STYLE -->
<style name="Nebular" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     .
     .
     .
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>

    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>

    <!-- these lines made it work for HOLO -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Nebular.Theme.ActionBarWidget</item>
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Nebular.Theme.ActionBarWidget</item>

</style>
```

popupmenu style

```
<!-- PopupMenu style -->
<style name="Nebular.PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#ff000000</item>
</style>
```

actionbar widget

```
<!-- "ActionBar Widget" (not sure if neccessary, doesnt work anyway :(  -->
<style name="Nebular.Theme.ActionBarWidget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Nebular.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```